# undefined project property from library displays differently than undefined project property within project

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a function to retrieve a project property. I pass the value of the variable
name.

I wrote a testing routine. In the test routine a do a similar getProperty with
the same variable name. The testing routine is in a different project than
the library function. I did this to test in the real situation. I know that
each project has its own project properties definitions.

Here is the get routine from the library:

```
function  lib_get(pvar)
{
   return ScriptProperties.getProperty(pvar);
}
```

Here is the testing routine:

```
function lib_test()
{
     var u = ScriptProperties.getProperty("u");

     var t = lib_get("u");  

     Browser.msgBox(" u:"+u+" t: "+t);
}
```

The variable "u" is not defined in either project.

```
The display shows "U" has a value of "null", 

and "t" has a value of "undefined".
```

Is this the way the functions are suppose to work? Should I accept that
this difference is normal and operate under this assumption for all future time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the library's prefix when you call a function from that library.

```
var t = myLibrary.lib_get("u");
```

Where "myLibrary" is the name of the library as you defined it in the Manage Libraries dialog.